# How to handle nav dropdown submenu hover with parent link

Tags: jquery, html, menu, navigation, submenu

A website I have designed uses a nav menu that shows sub menus on `:hover` but it is working fine on the desktop and laptop devices.

The big issue is that when nav menu open on mobile or tablet devices it is not showing sub menu when :hover  on parent?

The goal is this:

- When nav menu open on mobile or tablet devices function should be display sub menu and also parent a href link should clickable while sub menu is showing

Is there anything that can be improved and/or do you see any problems with this approach?

**Html**

```js
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
    $(function() { // DOM ready
   // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
   $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').hover(function(e) {
     $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
     // Close one dropdown when selecting another
     $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
     e.stopPropagation();
   });
   // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
   $('html').click(function() {
     $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
   });
   // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
   $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
     $('nav ul').slideToggle();
   });
   // Hamburger to X toggle
   $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
     this.classList.toggle('active');
   });
    }); // end DOM ready
  })(jQuery); // end jQuery
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul class="primary-nav">
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="test.php">test</a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
     <li>
       <a href="#!">Hello</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#!">Hello2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#!">Demo</a>
     </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="demo2.php">demo2</a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
     <li>
       <a href="#!">testing</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#!">new</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#!">basic</a>
     </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: if you switch from jQuery based hover to css based hover mobile devices will actually understand hovers and show content on click. Note, the parent isn't clickable anymore in that case

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    breakpoint: 768,
    format: "multitoggle"
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen li:hover > ul > li {
  height: auto;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  color: #dddddd;
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
  color: #dddddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  top: 23px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  top: 23px;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
  background: #262626;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 19px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:after {
  top: 15px;
  right: 13px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:before {
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- MenuMaker Plugin -->
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Test</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hello 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Hello 3</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Demo</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Basic</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bullseye"></i> Other</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.1.1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.1.2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.1.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 1.3</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.3.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.3.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.3.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4.1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4.1.1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4.1.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```